# construct a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

This is an assignment question, please give hints only thank you!

Construct a ring homomorphism $f: R \rightarrow S$ such that $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal, and $S$ is not a field.

I know that $I\subseteq R$ is a maximal ideal iff $R/I$ is a field.

I thought of $R$ being $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but then $\ker(f)$ would have to be $n\mathbb{Z}$ and n would have to be a prime number. Then, what would be a suitable $S$ in this case?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Maximal ideals are important because the quotient rings of maximal ideals are simple rings, and in the special case of unital commutative rings they are also fields."  This seems to give a hint about in which direction to look.

Comment: how is this possible? dosent it contradict your statement that the quotient ring sholud be a field?

Comment: I'm saying that the original statement that $R/I$ must be a field presupposes that the ring is commutative.  This suggests that one could find a ring $R$ that is noncommutative with a maximal ideal $I$ such that $R/I$ is a simple ring but not a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint you ask for:  the map doesn't have to be surjective.

---

The solution (for others looking at the question): Just let $R=\Bbb Z$ and $S=\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/p$ and map

> $$\phi:\begin{cases}\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/p\\ x\mapsto (0, x\mod p)\end{cases}$$

Clearly $S$ is not a field, and clearly the kernel is $(p)$ which is a maximal ideal of $R$.

The main trick of it:  don't demand that $S=\text{Im}( \phi)$ is the full image, surjective homomorphisms won't work since the first isomorphism theorem tells you the image is a field. But the image doesn't have to be the full co-domain, so we just slap on an extra $\Bbb Z$ to make it not a field.

---

**Edit (addendum)**: In the case this is demanded to be a unital homomorphism, you just tweak things and let $R=\Bbb Z/p$ and $S=\Bbb Z/p\oplus\Bbb Z/p$. Then let

$$\phi:\begin{cases} R\to S \\ x\mapsto (x,x)\end{cases}$$

Here the kernel is $\{0\}$ because the map is injective, and again $S$ is not a field since $(0,1)\cdot (1,0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are looking for a unital ring homomorphism, i.e. 1 goes to 1.

Comment: This is really above what I can come up with, wow, thank you!

Comment: @ET93 why is that? I cannot see anything in the context that would indicate that.

Comment: xD Because I know where the question is from.

Comment: @ET93 May I ask a silly question: what is the kernel of the unital homomorphism?

Comment: @ET93 well fair enough, I've added a second example.

Comment: @Blackgirl5 if ET93 is correct, just see my new addendum, same hint holds for the original question.

Comment: @AdamHughes Hints only :(